# Could servers with different net-ids be in the same VLAN

Tags: networking, ip, vlan

Could I theoretically have one server with an ip address of : 10.10.10.1 and another server with the ip : 10.10.11.2.
sign them the same vlan id on the switch, and have communication between them (say I give one of them a default gateway of the other)

Comment: What's the netmask?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure - if you are using a netmask that encloses both adresses. The VLAN is managing your Layer 2 connectivity, TCP/IP operates Layer 3.

Answer (score 2):

VLAN's operate at Layer 2. IP operates at Layer 3. Hosts in different Layer 3 networks can communicate between each other as long as you have the appropriate routing configured. The VLAN's don't have anything to do with it.